# How to break down your ios project to the classes and objects you need after designing the project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8

I took couple of classes with treehouse and did few small projects.

Right now I want to develop my first app from beginning to end and I would love to get some guidance how to break things down.

My project is a to do app, I designed the pages with sketch and now I want to open the project in xcode and I'm trying to figure out where do I start...

I'm sorry if the question is inappropriate and have no code, but I believe there are allot of beginners who could use this guidance.

Thanks for the support

Comment: Why such questions in past were downvoted a lot for obvious reasons, but this opposite...

Comment: Try it.  Do it wrong.  Try again.  Repeat for 20 years or so.

Comment: This is just going to generate opinion answers. There are many ways of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing iOS Applications is an organic process. You will start off with one approach, and then discover a need to change things up along the way. There isn't always a "magic formula", you have to be willing to adapt as new challenges come along.

With that said, there are best practices, and design patterns used when creating iOS and OSX applications.

Some things that you will always find useful are:

**[The Model-View-Controller Pattern (MVC)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html)**
The MVC design pattern is the most common pattern for building iOS and OSX applications.

**[Object Oriented Programming (OOP)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/Introduction/Introduction.html)**
A solid understanding of how to leverage OOP will save you lots of headaches, and make your code easier to maintain. Learn the meaning of the terms "Loose Coupling" and "Separation of Concerns" and how OOP and the MVC Pattern work together to make your code stable and easy and maintain.

**[Learn Apple's iOS Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/miscellaneous/conceptual/iphoneostechoverview/iPhoneOSFrameworks/iPhoneOSFrameworks.html)**
You don't have to memorize every little bit of the framework, because it's massive, but over time you will start to memorize the elements that you use most often and it will become second nature. If you start off small and just study the parts of the framework that are relevant to your project(s), then soon you will start to discover a pattern emerging.

**[Keep Your Code Clean, and Keep Your Projects Organized](http://www.slideshare.net/MassimoOliviero/architecting-ios-project)**
Don't get in your own way by making things difficult to read, or making files difficult to find. When you are naming a function, variable, file, class, protocol, or a group in XCode, make sure you are asking yourself "is the name I am choosing self-describing?" Choose names that "document" your code and make its purpose clear. This will make your code easier to read for you, or for others, and more importantly, it will make your code easy to navigate and maintain after you revisit the code from a long absence. If you focus on keeping your code clean and your projects well organized, then many things will fall into place for you. If your code is a mess, then it will be a nightmare to debug when the bugs start piling in.

**[When in Doubt, Turn To the Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/)**
An often overlooked tool: [The Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/) is a comprehensive study guide with cookbooks, tutorials, sample projects, code samples and more. Furthermore, Apple makes video tutorials available through the [Member center](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action), which can be invaluable along with the [WWDC 2014 Videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/), which is great way to watch Apple engineers work, and discuss the latest advancements.

**---------** 
My advice would be to just start building your app and be prepared to learn and make mistakes along the way. If you make any mistakes, then learn from them! Ask yourself what you can do to make things better. Read code from other professionals to see how they structure their apps (github is a good place for this). Read books, and more books, watch videos tutorials, ask questions and always be learning.

Try watching this free course at iTunes University: [Developing iOS 7 Apps for iPhone and iPad](https://itunes.apple.com/en/course/developing-ios-7-apps-for/id733644550). It's really great at pushing your skills to the next level, and gets you asking all the right questions, and might even answer some of them for you.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I believe building a successful iOS app requires a solid understanding of the Model View Controller design pattern.

I suggest start with [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) and try to use it as guide when defining the different components of your project.

Good luck!

Comment: Except that hardly anyone ever adheres to MVC edicts.